# Centering a programatically created group not working in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have used the following code to group all the objects in the canvas and centering the group. Here the grouping is working but the centering is not working.

```
var objs = canvas.getObjects();

//create group
var group = new fabric.Group(objs);

group.center().setCoords();

canvas.setActiveGroup(group).renderAll();
```

I tried selecting all the objects manually using the mouse and tried this code in the console: `canvas.getActiveGroup().center()` and it worked fine.

What is the reason for this issue? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it worked using `canvas.centerObject()`:

```
var objs = canvas.getObjects();

//create group
var group = new fabric.Group(objs);

canvas.centerObject(group);

canvas.setActiveGroup(group).renderAll();
```

But I don't know why the `center()` is not working.